# Kill process by name

Tags: windows, kill-process

How can I kill a process by name on Windows with API functions only?

Comment: What Operation System? What platform?

Answer (score 4):

In a cmd window you can use `taskkill /F /im cmd.exe` to kill all cmd.exe programs.

The `/T` flag tells taskkill to forcefully kill the processes, whereas
`taskkill /im cmd.exe` gracefully shuts it down by sending a kill signal.

more information on taskkill can be found [here](https://www.windows-commandline.com/taskkill-kill-process/)

another great tool for terminating processes is [wmic](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tgp/scsadmins/winadmin/WMIC_Queries.txt)

Answer (score 1):

If by kill you mean terminate with extreme prejudice,theres's always TerminateProcess. I'd advise against using it if you can find another way (such as posting WM_CLOSE to the main window), because loaded DLLs don't get unloaded properly when you call TerminateProcess, so used resources might not get released.

The real problem is how to get from a name to a process ID, this normally involves

EnumProcesses() 
EnumProcessModules()
 
GetModuleFileNameEx()
GetModuleBaseName()

and comparing the resulting base module name against what you're looking for. But there may be more than one instance of a module name executing on a system. How would you differentiate between instances in this circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

```
killall yourprocess
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall (note that this only applies on Linux, as you haven't specified your OS)

Comment: Note that this kills all processes with the name `yourprocess`. If you have multiple instances of this process, that might be a problem.

Comment: @Juri Glass: Indeed. Alas, there's no way to tell them apart using just the name. You could `pgrep` and then `kill` only the first one, but that still doesn't solve anything - how do you know it's the right one? You don't.

Comment: @Gilboss: OK. It makes sense to provide enough details in the question - so that you'll get relevant answers back.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean on Windows, use [ZwQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx) and [TerminateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  See here for a detailed sample: [How to kill a process given a name](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/killprocess.aspx)